# Applying a homography (OpenCV) to a CALayer via CATransform3D

Tags: ios, opencv

I am playing with AR on iPhone and I have a problem in applying a homography to a CALayer which I am not able to solve. So I ask for your help.

The application

- supports only the orientation Landscape right;
- receives a stream of 640x480 frames from the iPhone camera;
- process each frame with OpenCV functions:
- trying to find a homography that maps a target image onto the frame received from the camera.

The first figure shows that the homography computed is correct: the coloured target image is placed exactly on top of its corresponding gray-level image contained in the frame. The gray-level frame corresponds to the processed RGB camera frame received from the camera. See screenshot.

[image: Correct alignment]

As a second step, I tried to overlay a movie on top of the recognized target image. I added a `MPMoviePlayerController`, then transformed the computed homography `F` into a 4x4 CATransform3D matrix `ttt`.

The values of the matrix `ttt` are set in the following way (`F` has a row major order, ttt needs to be column major):

```
 CATransform3D ttt;
 ttt.m11 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(0,0);
 ttt.m12 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(1,0);
 ttt.m13 = (CGFloat) 0;
 ttt.m14 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(2,0);

 ttt.m21 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(0,1);
 ttt.m22 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(1,1);
 ttt.m23 = (CGFloat) 0;
 ttt.m24 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(2,1);

 ttt.m31 = (CGFloat) 0;
 ttt.m32 = (CGFloat) 0;
 ttt.m33 = (CGFloat) 1;
 ttt.m34 = (CGFloat) 0;

 ttt.m41 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(0,2); 
 ttt.m42 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(1,2);
 ttt.m43 = (CGFloat) 0;
 ttt.m44 = (CGFloat) F.at<double>(2,2);
```

However, When I use the matrix above as the transform property of the CALayer, the alignment is not correct. See screenshot.

[image: The video placement is wrong]
The CALayer properties are configured as follows:

```
    [moviePlayer.view.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480)];
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];

    [moviePlayer.view.layer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480)];

    [moviePlayer.view.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    CGFloat borderW = 4.0;
    moviePlayer.view.layer.borderWidth = borderW;
    CGColorRef borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    moviePlayer.view.layer.borderColor = borderColor;
```

The movie dimensions are 480x270.

May be there is a problem related to the aspect ratio, but after reading quite a lot of documentation I have no other idea to test. So I hope someone can help me.